# Java Callback Execution in Thread Executed After run()

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, job-queue

I'm using a job queue library, where you define `Job`s and post them to a `JobManager`. The `JobManager` has a `ThreadGroup` with workers that pull `Job`s off of a queue and call `Job.onRun()`.

The amount of threads are set by giving a max and min amount of threads, a load factor (how many outstanding jobs can a worker thread have before creating a new one) and an idle timeout for any of the threads above min. Therefore, a worker thread's `run()` will terminate if it has no new jobs, and its idle timeout is reached.

In some `Job`s I'm using libraries that only expose an async API. Is it safe to use these in onRun()?

For example, if I want to make a network request that takes a callback which provides me with a response will the callback get called:

```
@Override
public void onRun() throws Throwable {
    client.doRequest(request, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestComplete(Response response) {
            //is this guaranteed to get called?
        }
    });
    //since we now return from onRun() will onRequestComplete() get called?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to do as long as you know that the following are true (while the process is alive):

1. Every Job's `onRun()` method will always be executed (eventually), and
2. Every async API that you use will *always* call its callback method (even when there are exceptions).

Comment: Every `onRun()` will eventually get executed, and the callback method is always called (even with exceptions). The process is not tied to these threads (there is a separate main thread). Can you explain why it is safe?

Comment: Are you sure you actually have multiple processes? Every instance of the VM has one and only one process (which can have many threads). In any case, if both of my conditions are true, then it must be that every callback will eventually be called. Unless, of course, the process that contains all the threads is killed (e.g., when the user explicitly kills the process, or the computer loses power) -- but in this case nothing is ever truly "safe".

Comment: I worded my response a little awkwardly. What I meant to say was that all of these threads are in one process, and I'm only asking in the context of the process not dying.

Answer (score 4):

Yes your callback will run as long as the process is still alive.

If you want to see I created a program to simulate just that. It has three classes just drop them in any one package and run and you will see your self. This depicts even when your job thread completes callback still comes.
I hope it helps :)

**Class 1**

```
public class Client {
    private static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Time elapsed in ms:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        Client client = new Client();
        client.executeJob();
        try {
            System.out.println("Main thread sleeping");
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread finishing");
    }

    public void executeJob() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Job job = new Job();
                System.out.println("Calling Job with Asyc - Time elapsed in ms:" 
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
                job.doRequest("Calling Async", new CallBack() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRequestComplete(String response) {
                        System.out.println("Got my callback eventhough job that started the Async is over - Time elapsed in ms:" 
                                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
                    }
                });
                System.out.println("Job thread finishing");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

**Class 2**

```
public abstract class CallBack {
    public abstract void onRequestComplete(String response);
}
```

**Class 3**

```
public class Job {
    public void doRequest(String request, final CallBack callBack){
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Async Long running task
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    callBack.onRequestComplete("Long Async task Completed-- Sending response back");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and *No*

**YES:** You provide an instance of an `Callback` to the `client` object. The client will simply call the `onRequestComplete` Method after getting the Response (from server).

**NO:** If there is no more Thread running and there are outstanding Requests, they may becanceled, because the application will be stopped.

But I think you were asking about the normal execution and not the shutdown of the JVM.

So my guess is **YES**, but I don't know the implementation of client (I guess it starts an Thread of has some kind of eventmechanism inside).

Comment: The process is not tied to these threads (there is a separate main thread). Can you explain why it is safe?